# Elegant way to replacing/editing specific JSON text in a file?

Tags: c#, json, replace

Suppose I have a JSON text file in which there are multiple items .. I need to edit a specific item in it by adding another key/value pair to it. This change needs to be done ***only for that one specific item*** in the JSON file, and not the other items in that text file. Also, the change needs to be able to withstand future changes to any other parts of the text file.

For example, suppose the text file has entries like this (`...` means more similar entries):

```
{
    "Blah": "Blah",
    "Blah": "Blah",
    "Blah": "Blah",
    "Blah": "Blah",
    "TopologyResources": [
        .....
        ,
        {
          "ResourceUri": "https://proto23.devspace.com/merger",
          "ActAsPrivileges": [
            "UserData.Read",
            "UserData.ReadWrite"
          ],
          "AppOnlyPrivileges": [
            "UserData.Read",
            "UserData.ReadWrite",
            "UserMeetingData-Internal.ReadWrite"
          ]
        },
        .....
    ]
}
```

I want to change the above to this (notice the addition of the `GlobalTopologyAccessScopes` key:

```
{
    "Blah": "Blah",
    "Blah": "Blah",
    "Blah": "Blah",
    "Blah": "Blah",
    "TopologyResources": [
        .....
        ,
        {
          "ResourceUri": "https://proto23.devspace.com/merger",
          "ActAsPrivileges": [
            "UserData.Read",
            "UserData.ReadWrite"
          ],
          "AppOnlyPrivileges": [
            "UserData.Read",
            "UserData.ReadWrite",
            "UserMeetingData-Internal.ReadWrite"
          ],
          "GlobalTopologyAccessScopes": [
            {
              "ScopeType": "Dev",
              "AccessType": "All"
            }
          ]
        },
        .....
    ]
}
```

Is there any better more elegant way of doing this change besides the code below which looks ugly ?

```
string originalText = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

            string find = "    {\r\n      \"ResourceUri\": \"https://proto23.devspace.com/merger\",\r\n      \"ActAsPrivileges\": [\r\n        \"UserData.Read\",\r\n        \"UserData.ReadWrite\"\r\n      ],\r\n      \"AppOnlyPrivileges\": [\r\n        \"UserData.Read\",\r\n        \"UserData.ReadWrite\",\r\n        \"UserMeetingData-Internal.ReadWrite\"\r\n      ]\r\n    }";
            string replace = "    {\r\n      \"ResourceUri\": \"https://proto23.devspace.com/merger\",\r\n      \"ActAsPrivileges\": [\r\n        \"UserData.Read\",\r\n        \"UserData.ReadWrite\"\r\n      ],\r\n      \"AppOnlyPrivileges\": [\r\n        \"UserData.Read\",\r\n        \"UserData.ReadWrite\",\r\n        \"UserMeetingData-Internal.ReadWrite\"\r\n      ],\r\n      \"GlobalTopologyAccessScopes\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"ScopeType\": \"Dev\",\r\n          \"AccessType\": \"All\"\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }";

            newText = originalText.Replace(find, replace);
            File.WriteAllText(filepath, newText);
```

Note: In case you're thinking of deserializing the JSON data to a C# class, make the change, and then write the serialized version again .. Let me tell you that there's no C# class to deserialize the json data to ..

**EDIT:** Basically the root level object has a key called `TopologyResources`, which is an array .. The `GlobalTopologyAccessScopes` key needs to be added to that object in that `TopologyResources` array which has `ResourceUri: https://proto23.devspace.com/merger`

Comment: Using [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)?

Comment: Can you give example code ?

Comment: Look at the "Json.NET Documentation" on that page. There are many, many samples for everything you could think of. For instance [Parsing to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm) and [Creating JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm)...

Comment: There are also tools that will take a JSON file and produce C# classes from it for you...

Answer (score 1):

Adding my final solution which is based on Pavel's deleted answer but with a few modifications. Since Pavel deleted his answer, I can't vote on his answer.

Anyway, this is what I did:

```
string filepath = @"C:\SomeFolder\someFile.xyz";
string originalText = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

JObject json = JObject.Parse(originalText);

if (json["TopologyResources"] is JArray resources)
{
    JObject correctObject = resources.Children<JObject>()
        .FirstOrDefault(pq => pq["ResourceUri"].ToString() == @"https://proto23.devspace.com/merger");

    if (correctObject != null)
    {
        var scopeDetail = new[] { new { ScopeType = "Dev", AccessType = "All" } };
        correctObject.Add("GlobalTopologyAccessScopes", JArray.FromObject(scopeDetail));
    }
}

var changedText = json.ToString();
File.WriteAllText(filepath, changedText);
```

I hope others find it useful.